# How to use Laravel Process to run the command "./vendor/bin/pint"?

Tags: laravel

This is how I tried to run the command "./vendor/bin/pint" with Laravel Process.

```
Process::run('./vendor/bin/pint', function (string $type, string $output) {
        echo $output;
    });
```

I got the error output as

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: can you try with this command: php vendor/bin/pint

Answer (score 1):

You can run Laravel pint by running the following command:

```
php vendor/bin/pint
```